# Vue Slots: How to provide TypeScript types about available slot names and scoped slots?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have created this example in the [Vue Playuground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UctOwzAQ/JWVOfRCbaXHYJAQJ258gC+huDRV/JC9gUOUf2fXddOiVvXFuzP78Iwn8Rqj/BmtaIXO29RHhGxxjC/G9y6GhPDWpS/YpeBgJRUnXL56Ml6rYwOVUoLWxaFDS5nmKkZxQeEhDwEbAoGO3p+id+gcMAVNpVTltFomAhTg/6zNsxF8f6QQsxFXk6dpYSX2ONh5vr9BF3H8/DMuHsXRhbXrojzk4MmniZtNJWh1CwVhjJzh3Ig9YsytUnm3ZbsOWYb0rSiSafTYOyttduvPFH6zTTTYCB5BL5xp5clk/pMLW8nO4pTvnK3iGxJO30DRbX5jBBTxlJ+tJrQaUDsvFc9/68ew0Q==)

Let's imagine we have a third-party component coming from a library, the `Card.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <slot name="slot1"></slot>
    <slot name="slot2" title="I am slot 2">
  </slot>
</template>
```

and this component is consumed within our application, where we leverage both a named slot and a scoped slot.

```
<script setup>
import Card from './Card.vue';
</script>

<template>
<Card>
    <template #slot1>
    <h1>
    I am slot 1
    </h1>
  </template>  
  <template #slot2="slotProps">
    <h1>
    {{slotProps.title}}
    </h1>
  </template>  
</Card>
</template>
```

However, coming from a React background where you don't have `slots` but rather `children` prop and `Component props`, what I struggle to understand is how to provide type information to a consumer.

How do I know, within my `App.vue` file, what slots name are available, and which scoped slot properties?

Comment: Vue has a limited support for TS in templates. Slots aren't covered

Comment: So in the Vue community, what's the recommended way to provide information about a third-party component? It's just "text" documentation (clearly stating which slots are available and which properties?)

Answer (score -3):

Use Vscode and install Volar plugin may help you. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDazY.png) of it in action.

From the Vue documentation on Tooling:

> The recommended IDE setup is VSCode + the Vue Language Features (Volar) extension. The extension provides syntax highlighting, TypeScript support, and intellisense for template expressions and component props.

[IDE Support on Vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#ide-support)

Comment: Welcome. As per SO guidelines, link only replies are not constricted answers, and are subject to deleting. You must include relevant info from the linked website so that a complete solution to OP's question is self contained in your answer. Otherwise, if the website were to become unavailable or it's content were to change your reply would become useless as SO quality would suffer. It is also not user friendly to make every visitor click around the web to find an answer that should be readily apparent. A kind user has already fixed this for you :-) But keep it in mind for future contributions.